# Push a directory to one remote but not another with Git

Tags: git, push

I am using Git as part of my web development workflow. I have a hook that creates a backup of the database before a commit. I then push everything up to a master repo for backup purposes. Then when I'm ready I push everything to the live server. However I do not want the database backups to be pushed to the live server for security.

Is there a way to tell Git to not copy the database backups when pushing to the live remote but still have it push the database backups to the master repo?

Comment: A push transfers based on *commits* (more precisely, git objects, but the difference is irrelevant for this comment).  So "what gets pushed" depends on what's in the commits to be pushed.  Thus, the question I have when you say "creates a backup" is: what *commits* does this add to the repository, if any?

Comment: I use the pre-commit hook to create a db backup and then add it to the repository using `git add db-backups/[DB name].sql.gz`

Comment: `git add` writes the blob to the repository and updates the index to include it, so that the `git commit` that occurs includes the file.  In other words, you're committing the backup along with your other changes, as if you had manually done the steps in your pre-commit hook.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to Git so that is likely part of the problem. I've been reading more and it sounds like maybe I should be using two branches. One to push to the master repo which would include the db-backups and one to the production repo. Would that make sense?

Comment: Well, you can do that, but then the master and production have two different commit-chains.  Think of them as separate lines of development, because that's what they will be.  It's not impossible to do but it's twice as much work.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a hook that creates a backup of the database before a commit.

Is this a local hook making local database backups?

Instead, you should make a database backup on a staging server in a post-update or pre-receive hook. This workflow might be suitable for one person, but you're going to have issues if someone else is committing sql dumps.

When you make the database dump in one of those hooks, don't put them in your git repo. Put them somewhere else on the file system. That way, your backups don't stay under version control.

A typical workflow will be:

1. work locally and make some commits
2. push your commits to remote
3. remote hook makes backup of database

If you have two remotes, one for staging and one for production, all you have to do is push to staging to make your backups and push to production to deploy the live project.

Comment: The remotes I have are for backup and production, the staging is done on my local machine. Also, the database is also on the local machine so the remotes don't have access to make a backup of it. I am trying to get the db backups to go to the backup repo but I don't want them going to the production repo.